# Connectivity of a graph constructed from another graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Suppose I am given a non-bipartite, undirected graph $G(V,E)$. I create a new graph We $G'(V', E')$ as follows: $V' = V \times V = \{(v_i,v_j) | v_i, v_j \in V\}, E' = \{((v_i,v_j),(v_k,v_l)) | (v_i,v_k),(v_j,v_l) \in E\}$.

Is there any reason why $G'$ is guaranteed to be connected? I guess it has something to do with non-bipartiteness and undirectedness of $G$, but have been thinking about it for hours and am still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to assume that $G$ is connected. I would use the fact that $G$ is non-bipartite only if it has an odd cycle. Given any two ordered pairs of vertices of $G$, show that you can walk from both pairs along the edges of $G'$ to pairs that have both vertices on the same odd cycle. Can you figure out how to walk from any pair to any pair in an odd cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You mean given $(v_i,v_j), (v_l,v_k)$ show that walking from these two pairs using the edges in $G'$ to a vertex $(v_w,v_w)$ in G', is equivalent to completing an odd cycle in $G$?

Comment: I mean you can walk from $(v_i, v_j)$ to $(v_l, v_k)$ by way of first walking to some $(u, w)$ where $u$ and $w$ are both on the odd cycle, walk along the cycle to some pair $(x, y)$ from which you can walk to $(v_l, v_k)$. Can you see how to get to some $(u, w)$ on the cycle from $(v_i, v_j)$?

Comment: Since $G$ is connected, there exists paths $(v_i,...,u)$ and $(v_j,...,w)$. If there these paths have the same length, we're done. If one is longer than the other, say the first path is longer, then on the shorter walk, we can walk back and forth between $u$ and $u_{-1}$, until the other walk reaches $w$. If the difference is even, then that is possible, but that's not possible if the difference is odd, since the first walk is at $u_{-1}$ when the second walk is at $w$. I'm still not seeing how that is related to the odd-cycle though.

Comment: Getting to $(u_{-1}, w)$ is just as good as getting to $(u, w)$, since the goal was just to get to both vertices on the odd cycle - we can just switch the names of $u$ and $u_{-1}$, if that's the case. Now that we are on the cycle, I claim you can walk along the cycle from $(u, w)$ to ANY pair on the cycle. Here it becomes important that the cycle is odd! Can you see how to do that?

Comment: I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Suppose you want to go from $(u, w)$ to $(x, y)$, where $u$, $w$, $x$, and $y$ are on the odd cycle. We can start by walking $u$ and $w$ in the same direction along the cycle until $u$ reaches $x$ and $w$ reaches some $z$, so we've walked to $(x, z)$. Now walk from $z$ to $y$ while $x$ alternates between $x$ and a neighbor of $x$ (call it $x_{-1}$). If we end up at $(x, y)$, we're done. But perhaps we are unlucky and end up at $(x_{-1}, y)$. In that case, just continue walking once around the odd cycle in the same fashion. By the time we get back to $y$, the first coordinate will be $x$!